# Why isn't my variable being assigned

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Ok I think my understanding of properties in objective c may not be what I thought it was.

In my program I have a singleton that contains my class.

In my class during the init I assign a value from the singleton to my property.

I then assign a value to a property of that property.

However it does not keep the value and when I do a compare of the value in the singleton nothing has changed.  What is going on here?  Any ideas?

```
@interface MainGameLoop : NSObject {
    MapData *mapData;
}

@property (retain) MapData *mapData;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    GlobalVariables *sharedManager = [GlobalVariables sharedManager];
    self.mapData = sharedManager.mapData;   
    return self;
}
```

In a function of my class:

works:

```
sharedManager.mapData.currentPlayer = newCurrentPlayer;
```

does nothing:

```
self.mapData.currentPlayer == newCurrentPlayer;
```

Comment: I question the need for a GlobalVariables class. First off, you don't need to put everything in classes in Objective-C; you can make real global variables just fine. (And stashing them in a singleton doesn't make them any less global or any less variable.) Second, why do you even need this singleton? Why not have the MainGameLoop object (which I might rename to “Game” or something) own the map data outright?

Comment: Also, I dispute that you have “a singleton [object] that contains my class”. There's not usually a reason for an object to own a class, unless the object dynamically creates instances of a caller-provided class (as NSObjectController and NSArrayController do). It looks more like your singleton owns an *instance* of the MapData class.

Comment: You are right it does just own an instance of the class.  I put it in a singleton because I kept having to pass the mapdata instance to all of my other classes via their constructor and it started to feel very time consuming.  I doubt it was the best way to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
self.mapData.currentPlayer == newCurrentPlayer;
```

Are you sure that you want two equal signs there?  That statement is syntactically correct and will evaluate to either true or false.

Comment: This is one of several reasons to turn on the “Unused Value” warning in the build settings.

Comment: wow.  It is funny when you are new at something you just have no confidence.  All sorts of crazy ideas were running through my head as to why this was happening and it turns out to be something crazy simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`==` is a Boolean operator, while `=` is an assignment operator. Like what Dave said, if you are using an `if` statement such as `if (self.mapData.currentPlayer == newCurrentPlayer) {…}`, you would want to use `==` because it would evaluate to `true` or `false`, while `=` would be used to set the value of a variable, which is what I think you are trying to do.

If it's any consolation, I've made that mistake too many times to count…

Something that I do is to use `NSLog()` or `printf()` to make sure that each step is working correctly.